# Nginx 403 forbidden for all files

Tags: nginx, centos, http-status-code-403, php

I have nginx installed with PHP-FPM on a CentOS 5 box, but am struggling to get it to serve any of my files - whether PHP or not.

Nginx is running as www-data:www-data, and the default "Welcome to nginx on EPEL" site (owned by root:root with 644 permissions) loads fine.

The nginx configuration file has an include directive for */etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf,* and I have a configuration file *example.com.conf*, thus:

```
server {
 listen 80;

 Virtual Host Name
 server_name www.example.com example.com;


 location / {
   root /home/demo/sites/example.com/public_html;
   index index.php index.htm index.html;
 }

 location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index  index.php;
  fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/demo/sites/example.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
  include        fastcgi_params;
 }
}
```

Despite public_html being owned by www-data:www-data with 2777 file permissions, this site fails to serve any content -

```
 [error] 4167#0: *4 open() "/home/demo/sites/example.com/public_html/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: XX.XXX.XXX.XX, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"
```

I've found numerous other posts with users getting 403s from nginx, but most that I have seen involve either more complex setups with Ruby/Passenger (which in the past I've actually succeeded with) or are only receiving errors when the upstream PHP-FPM is involved, so they seem to be of little help.

Have I done something silly here?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808813/nginx-serve-static-file-and-got-403-forbidden/46083622#46083622

Answer (score 378, accepted):

One permission requirement that is often overlooked is a user needs x permissions in every parent directory of a file to access that file.  Check the permissions on /, /home, /home/demo, etc. for www-data x access.  My guess is that /home is probably 770 and www-data can't chdir through it to get to any subdir.  If it is, try chmod o+x /home (or whatever dir is denying the request).

EDIT: To easily display all the permissions on a path, you can use `namei -om /path/to/check`

Comment: Same here. On my install of CentOS 6, /home/user dirs are set to 700 by default.

Comment: This guy talks about it too: (`chmod -4 +x /mypath` worked for me) http://nginxlibrary.com/403-forbidden-error/

Comment: Can someone explain why this behavior is different than apache which does NOT require every parent directory to have "x" permissions?!?

Comment: It isn't any different.  The only reason apache wouldn't also require x permission on parent directories is if it's running as root.

Comment: I ended up adding the www-data user to my personal user group and doing a chmod 710 to my root user folder. Worked like a charm. (On a debian based distro)

Comment: both the permission requirement and the namei tip helped me solve my issue.

Comment: I had to add +x to a parent folder of www/ even though all the sub-folders of www/ had the x-bit set. Wow, this took a while to figure out!

Comment: I would like to stress this point: the user needs permissions in EVERY PARENT DIRECTORY!

Comment: `autoindex on` might help

Comment: I have the right permissions for folder /var/www/html but I get a permission error. my question is after installing nginx we have a user and group nginx. we should use this user for folder owner?

Answer (score 333):

If you still see `permission denied` after verifying the permissions of the parent folders, it may be **SELinux** restricting access.

To check if SELinux is running:

```
# getenforce
```

To disable SELinux until next reboot:

```
# setenforce Permissive
```

Restart Nginx and see if the problem persists. To allow nginx to serve your www directory (make sure you turn SELinux back on before testing this. i.e, `setenforce Enforcing`)

```
# chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/www
```

See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586166/why-does-nginx-return-a-403-even-though-all-permissions-are-set-properly#answer-26228135) for more details

Comment: I couldn't figure out why whenever I started nginx it said ``open() "/usr/share/nginx/logs/xxxxxx.com-error_log" failed (13: Permission denied)`` after I checked the permissions and made sure it was being started as root. I came across this and found out SELinux was enabled. I disabled it and now it works no problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I still had an issue with permission denied for users owning their own FPM sockets so I was able to fix that one by changing the `user` from **nginx** to **root** in `/var/nginx/nginx.conf` - perhaps that will help someone else who comes across this issue. S/O to [DataPsyche](http://datapsyche.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/nginx-404-page-not-found-error-due-to-failed-13-permission-denied/) for the second part.

Comment: i think centos 6.6 has a bug. Selinux breaks nginx.

Comment: This is default behavior on CentOS 7 aswell.

Comment: Thank you thank you. 95% Of the info on this are about permissions, but when they are all set 775, I really was pulling my hear out (all 6 of them).

Comment: Im with everybody else that commented. I was ready to throw my computer out the window. Nginx was configured properly, permissions where properly set, I even went as far to make everything 777 and still got permissions denied error.

Comment: The better SELinux command for this is:
*semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/path/to/www(/.*)?"* and *restorecon -v /path/to/www*
this will automatically give all your files in this path the correct SELinux rights. Also when new files are added. Use httpd_sys_content_t if you only need reading rights.

Comment: On Centos 7 (SELinux enabled), the simplest fix for me was

    `setsebool httpd_read_user_content on`
(For static files hosted from a home directory, chmod'ed to world-readable)
 - Though I guess @KapiteinWitbaard's method above is more secure.

Comment: Thank you, i was looking all night for your solution, even set chown to nginx and 777 to all files in the directory but no success! You are great!

Comment: Seems that there's no way this works in RHEL 6.x (and probably centos 6). There needs some additional steps in configuring selinux and perhaps even  modifying things about Red Hat itself. Give up on any attempt to try to get it working on RHEL 6, I've been looking all over.

Comment: Dude this answer was super useful for Fedora. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Work for me on Centos 7

Answer (score 86):

I solved this problem by adding user settings.

in nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 4;
user username;
```

change the 'username' with linux user name.

Comment: I believe this answer is better security wise than the accepted answer. You don't have to go messing around with the permissions on your home folder (which could contain sensitive information) and if you're doing development with nginx, it saves you from having to upload weird file permissions to SCM.

Comment: The added permissions on the home directory are execute, not read, thus no sensitive information is (in theory) revealed (except, in this case, perhaps to a malicious PHP script which recurses upwards and knows the location of the sensitive files within another directory accessible to www-data).
You'll also notice that in the original question, my nginx was running as "www-data" - the configuration values here were already set as desired.

Comment: Had to add usergroup as well: user usegroup.

Comment: Worked for me as well (just as chmodding the dir to nginx:nginx). I prefer this solution though so I can have my document root owned by another user than nginx. Thanks Anderson for pointing this out.

Comment: saved my day. by the way what if the machine has multiple users and each user has his own website, how do i deal with it?

Comment: I believe this is the best solution

Answer (score 53):

I've got this error and I finally solved it with the command below.

```
restorecon -r /var/www/html
```

The issue is caused when you mv something from one place to another. It preserves the selinux context of the original when you move it, so if you untar something in /home or /tmp it gets given an selinux context that matches its location. Now you mv that to /var/www/html and it takes the context saying it belongs in /tmp or /home with it and httpd is not allowed by policy to access those files.

If you cp the files instead of mv them, the selinux context gets assigned according to the location you're copying to, not where it's coming from. Running restorecon puts the context back to its default and fixes it too.

Comment: Thanks @jsina, this helped me a lot

Comment: Damn, *＋1*, me too.

Comment: This was my problem as well.

Answer (score 24):

I've tried different cases and only when owner was set to nginx (`chown -R nginx:nginx "/var/www/myfolder"`) - it started to work as expected.

Comment: Worked for me as well. I suspect this happens because even though nginx is started as root, it spawns processes under the user that is specified in the nginx.conf file, which is "user nginx;" by default. Changing the user to the user who owns your document root should also work as Anderson suggested.

Comment: Mr. Anderson? No! Andron ;)

Comment: Apologies Mr. Andron ;) I can't seem to edit the previous comment anymore though...

Comment: Sure, not a problem. Now I was as Anderson :) and need to write some fairy tales...

Comment: Isn't this a security issue ?

Answer (score 11):

If you're using SELinux, just type:

```
sudo chcon -v -R --type=httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/www/
```

This will fix permission issue.

Comment: It would be helpful to add an explanation as to what this command does.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I had the same issue. I tried every answer above, nothing worked. What fixed it for me though was removing the domain, and adding it again. I'm using Plesk, and I installed Nginx AFTER the domain was already there.

Did a local backup to /var/www/backups first though. So I could easily copy back the files.

Strange problem....

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue, using Plesk Onyx 17. Instead of messing up with rights etc., solution was to add nginx user into psacln group, in which all the other domain owners (users) were:

```
usermod -aG psacln nginx
```

Now nginx has rights to access .htaccess or any other file necessary to properly show the content.

On the other hand, also make sure that Apache is in psaserv group, to serve static content:

```
usermod -aG psaserv apache
```

And don't forget to restart both Apache and Nginx in Plesk after! (and reload pages with Ctrl-F5)

Comment: This is the correct answer and it's most likely `usermod -aG username www-data` on most setups.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue but above solutions did not help.

So, after lot of struggle I found out that **sestatus** was set to enforce which blocks all the ports and by setting it to permissive all the issues were resolved.

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

Hope this helps someone like me.

Comment: While that might have fixed your problem - congrats! - that's a bit sad :-(
See [stopdisablingselinux.com](https://stopdisablingselinux.com) - could you find a different workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I dug myself into a slight variant on this problem by mistakenly running the `setfacl` command. I ran:

```
sudo setfacl -m user:nginx:r /home/foo/bar
```

I abandoned this route in favor of adding `nginx` to the `foo` group, but that custom ACL was foiling nginx's attempts to access the file. I cleared it by running:

```
sudo setfacl -b /home/foo/bar
```

And then nginx was able to access the files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, make sure the `index` NGINX directive in the server block contains a index.php:

`index index.php index.html;`

For more info checkout the [index directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

#### You meet the  403 Forbidden on nginx server ?

> curl -v http://fastcsv.com/fonts/Iosevka/WOFF2/IosevkaFixed-Regular.WOFF2

```
* 
* Connected to fastcsv.com (18.141.78.8) port 80 (#0)
> GET /fonts/Iosevka/WOFF2/IosevkaFixed-Regular.WOFF2 HTTP/1.1
>
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

#### Be patient, perform these steps(6):

1. **which user** nginx is running on ? - sudo if needed

> $ps -ef | grep nginx

```
nginx    17039 20103  0 07:33 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
nginx    17040 20103  0 07:33 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
root     20103     1  0  2022 ?        00:00:01 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
```

- nginx, root. you need to make sure that nginx, root must have permission. let's take nginx for example.

2. **check user permission** to file, my nginx config looks like `root /var/www/readcsv;`, so:

> $sudo -u nginx stat /var/www/readcsv/fonts/Iosevka/WOFF2/IosevkaFixed-Regular.WOFF2

```
stat: cannot stat ‘/var/www/readcsv/fonts/Iosevka/WOFF2/IosevkaFixed-Regular.woff2’: Permission denied
```

2.1. check permission of parent folders, one by one:

> $sudo -u nginx stat /var/www/readcsv/fonts/Iosevka/WOFF2

```
stat: cannot stat ‘/var/www/readcsv/fonts/Iosevka/WOFF2/’: Permission denied
```

2.2. until meets the good status:

> $sudo -u nginx stat /var/www/readcsv/fonts/Iosevka/

```
 File: ‘/var/www/readcsv/fonts/Iosevka/’
 Size: 30          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: ca01h/51713d    Inode: 159576725   Links: 4
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
Access: 2024-03-16 07:46:40.565625903 +0000
Modify: 2024-03-16 07:46:38.306635661 +0000
Change: 2024-03-16 07:46:38.306635661 +0000
```

3. **set permission**, nginx user don't have permission to:

3.1. folder /var/www/readcsv/fonts/Iosevka/WOFF2 , use chmod 755:

> $chmod 755 /var/www/readcsv/fonts/Iosevka/WOFF2

3.2. file /var/www/readcsv/fonts/Iosevka/WOFF2/IosevkaFixed-Regular.woff2 , use chmod 644:

> $chmod 644 /var/www/readcsv/fonts/Iosevka/WOFF2/IosevkaFixed-Regular.WOFF2

4. validate permission to file:

> $sudo -u nginx stat /var/www/readcsv/fonts/Iosevka/WOFF2/IosevkaFixed-Regular.WOFF2

```
 File: ‘/var/www/readcsv/fonts/Iosevka/WOFF2/IosevkaFixed-Regular.WOFF2’
 Size: 1102624     Blocks: 2160       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: ca01h/51713d    Inode: 13676       Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
Access: 2024-03-16 07:57:21.441857634 +0000
Modify: 2024-03-16 07:42:44.202646066 +0000
Change: 2024-03-16 07:57:19.709865115 +0000
Birth: -
```

5. End-user validation:

> $curl -v http://fastcsv.com/fonts/Iosevka/WOFF2/IosevkaFixed-Regular.WOFF2

```
�u�<��tY{�����9x �M                       ����)`$I�$I�S�<��@�
������ദ5���m-.nkqq[[m|�z
��|r�C7               8���Ӡ�T���mvYM@�\
g�1o!u�Eg���]ܨ-���и���$%�)���J��Q"�
```

happy 403!

P/S: if you concern about 644, 755 codes, please find at:

https://www.multacom.com/faq/password_protection/file_permissions.htm

```
Some file permission examples:

777 - all can read/write/execute (full access).
755 - owner can read/write/execute, group/others can read/execute.
644 - owner can read/write, group/others can read only.

Some directory permission examples:

777 - all can read/write/search.
755 - owner can read/write/search, others and group can only search.
```