# Nginx serve static file and got 403 forbidden

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

Just want to help somebody out. yes ,you just want to serve static file using nginx, and you got everything right in **nginx.conf**:

```
location /static {
       autoindex on;
       #root /root/downloads/boxes/;
       alias /root/downloads/boxes/;
      }
```

But , in the end , you failed. You got "403 forbidden" from browser...

----------------------------------------**The Answer Below:**----------------------------------------

The Solution is very Simple:

---

**Way 1 : Run nginx as the user as the '/root/downloads/boxes/' owner**

In **nginx.conf** :

```
＃user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
```

YES, in the first line "**＃user  noboy;**" , just delete "**#**" , and change "**nobody**" to your own username in Linux/OS X, i.e change to "**root**" for test. The restart nginx.

**Attention** , You'd better not run **nginx** as **root**! Here just for testing, it's dangerous for the Hacker.

For more reference , see [nginx (engine X) – What a Pain in the BUM! [13: Permission denied]](http://nicholasorr.com/blog/2008/07/22/nginx-engine-x-what-a-pain-in-the-bum/)

---

**Way 2 : Change '/root/downloads/boxes/' owner to 'www-data' or 'nobody'**

In **Terminal**:

```
ps aux | grep nginx
```

Get the username of running nginx . It should be **'www-data'** or **'nobody'** determined by the version of nginx. Then hit in Terminal(use **'www-data'** for example):

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /root/downloads/boxes/
```

------------------------------**One More Important Thing Is:**------------------------------

These parent directories **"/"**, **"/root"**, **"/root/downloads"** should give the execute(x) permission to **'www-data'** or **'nobody'**. i.e.

```
ls -al /root
chmod o+x /root
chmod o+x /root/downloads
```

For more reference , see [Resolving "403 Forbidden" error](http://nginxlibrary.com/403-forbidden-error/) and [Nginx 403 forbidden for all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795350/nginx-403-forbidden-for-all-files)

Comment: you can also give the files permission to the group nginx is in, which is what is usually done, and also a little bit more logical

Comment: @rednaw, i'm new in stackoverflow too, sorry for the pervious comment,  yes , i did it following you answer, but i failed again.  i did changed owner to the file , but the browser show me the "403 forbidden".

Comment: did you restart nginx? also, nginx has a error log files (usually in `/var/log/nginx/`) where you can find more information, check the error and access log for example. BTW, maybe you should comment on my answer instead of your question.

Comment: `user root` worked perfectly for me on my development machine

Comment: @no_answer_not_upvoted , hey man , be careful with "root" , if a hacker hack you nginx server , root will be the hacker .

Comment: Don't run nginx as root please!

Comment: @rednaw thank you. I vow to make "did you restart nginx?" my go-to first step

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You should give nginx permissions to read the file. That means you should give the user that runs the nginx process permissions to read the file.

This user that runs the nginx process is configurable with the `user` directive in the nginx config, usually located somewhere on the top of `nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#user

The second argument you give to `user` is the group, but if you don't specify it, it uses the same one as the user, so in my example the user and the group both are `www-data`.

Now the files you want to serve with nginx should have the correct permissions. Nginx should have permissions to read the files. You can give the group `www-data` read permissions to a file like this:

```
chown :www-data my-file.html
```

http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown

With `chown` you can change the user and group owner of a file. In this command I only change the group, if you would change the user too you would specify the username **before** the colon, like `chown www-data:www-data my-file.html`. But setting the group permissions correct should be enough for nginx to be able to read the file.

Comment: `user root` made the problem go away and never, ever show its face again. (may the hyperventilation begin! ;-)

Comment: It might be an easy fix, but running programs as root can be dangerous. If there's an exploid in Nginx, and it's running as root, a cracker might be able to take over the complete OS.

Comment: see my hyperventilation remark. yes, it is a valid concern but often the machine is dedicated to nginx or has no critical information so even if a cracker takes over it is no big deal. and again it is indeed valid if you are running nginx on a serer which also has all your company IP and your email

Comment: i did upvote your answer btw because it helps for the times when you do need to do things right

Answer (score 54):

Since Nginx is handling the static files directly, it needs access to 
the appropriate directories. We need to give it executable permissions for our home directory.

The safest way to do this is to add the Nginx user to our own user group. We can then add the executable permission to the group owners of our home directory, giving just enough access for Nginx to serve the files:

**CentOS / Fedora**

```
  sudo usermod -a -G your_user nginx

  chmod 710 /home/your_user
```

> Set ***SELinux*** to globally permissive mode, run:
>
> `sudo setenforce 0`
>
> for more info, please visit
>   https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-plus-with-selinux/

**Ubuntu / Debian**

```
  sudo usermod -a -G your_user www-data

  sudo chown -R :www-data /path/to/your/static/folder
```

Comment: Thanks! I searched online for hours and only your answer helped. Appreciate it!!

Comment: The "Ubuntu" solution resulted that now I can't login by ssh anymore!

Comment: The ubuntu solution worked for me thanks!

Comment: In the same folder, all files have the same permission flags, but only one of the files cannot be accessed (with nginx's permission denied error). Set SELinux to permissive mode addressed my problem.

Answer (score 19):

for accepted answer

> `sudo chown -R :www-data static_folder`

for changing group owner of all files in that folder

Comment: a very straight forward answer.

Answer (score 15):

I ran into this issue with a Django project. Changing user permissions and groups didn't work. However, moving the entire static folder from my project to /var/www did.

Copy your project static files to /var/www/static

```
# cp -r /project/static /var/www/static
```

Point nginx to proper directory

```
# sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name _;

        location /static/ {
                root /var/www;
        }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }

}
```

Test nginx config and reload

```
# sudo nginx -t
# sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

Comment: Every single answer didn't work except this. Thank you so much!

Comment: The same, this answer is the only answer that works for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 11):

For me is was SElinux, I had to run the following: (RHEL/Centos on AWS)

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on 
chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/
```

Comment: Thank you! I’m using Fedora on my remote dev box, and am not used to SELinux. This was exactly the comment I was looking for :)

Comment: Just `chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/` works like a charm

Comment: Had no problem running Flask with Nginx on Centos 7. Updated to Almalinux recently and since then had 403 forbidden and tore my hair out. Changing user permissions didn't do anything good. This has finally worked for me but used the command on my static folder instead of /var/ww/! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

After digging into very useful answers decided to collect everything related to permissions as a recipe. Specifically, **the simplest solution with maximal security** (=minimal permissions).

1. Suppose we deploy the site as user `admin`, that is, she owns site dir and everything within. We do **not** want to run nginx as this user (too many permissions). It's OK for testing, not for prod.
2. By default Nginx runs workers as a user `nginx`, that is, config contains line `user nginx`
3. By default user `nginx` is in the group with the same name: `nginx`.
4. We want to give minimal permissions to user `nginx` without changing file ownership. This seems to be the most secure of naive options.
5. In order to serve static files, the minimal required permissions in the folders hierarchy (see the group permissions) should be like this (use the command `namei -l /home/admin/WebProject/site/static/hmenu.css`):

   dr-xr-xr-x root  root  /
   drwxr-xr-x root  root  home
   drwxr-x--- admin nginx admin
   drwx--x--- admin nginx WebProject
   drwx--x--- admin nginx site
   drwx--x--- admin nginx static
   -rwxr----- admin nginx hmenu.css
6. Next, how to get this beautiful picture? To change group ownership for dirs, we first apply `sudo chown :nginx /home/admin/WebProject/site/static` and then repeat the command stripping dirs from the right one-by-one.
7. To change permissions for dirs, we apply `sudo chmod g+x /home/admin/WebProject/site/static` and again strip dirs.
8. Change group for the files in the /static dir: `sudo chown -R :nginx /home/admin/WebProject/site/static`
9. Finally, change permissions for the files in the /static dir: `sudo chmod g+r /home/admin/WebProject/site/static/*`

(Of course one can create a dedicated group and change the user name, but this would obscure the narration with unimportant details.)

Comment: Actually, the user should be able to access to all directories in the path.

Changing the group of `/home/admin/WebProject/site/static/static` is not enough if the user can't access `/home/admin/WebProject/site` or `/home/admin/WebProject/' or `/home/admin`.

Answer (score 5):

Setting user root in nginx can be really dangerous. Having to set permissions to all file hierarchy can be cumbersome (imagine the folder's full path is under more than 10 subfolders).

What I'd do is to mirror the folder you want to share, under /usr/share/nginx/any_folder_name with permissions for nginx's configured user (usually www-data). That you can do with bindfs.

In your case I would do:

```
sudo bindfs -u www-data -g www-data /root/downloads/boxes/ /usr/share/nginx/root_boxes
```

It will mount /root/downloads/boxes into /usr/share/nginx/root_boxes with all permissions for user www-data. Now you set that path in your location block config

```
location /static {
   autoindex on;
   alias /usr/share/nginx/root_boxes/;
  }
```

Comment: after testing different setups with chmod etc. this looked to me the best suitable (and most safe) way. finally worked for me. Thanks man! :)

Comment: This method was helpful for me. I changed ownership and permissions for my static folder, but apparently my working path didn't allow Nginx to access. I did'n want to give to www-data user-group permissions all across the root directory upwards. Nice solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try the accepted answer by @gitaarik, and if it still gives `403 Forbidden` or `404 Not Found` and your location target is `/` read on.

I also experienced this issue, but none of the permission changes mentioned above solved my problem.  It was solved by adding the `root` directive because I was defining the root location (`/`) and accidentally used the `alias` directive when I should have used the `root` directive.

The configuration is accepted, but gives `403 Forbidden`, or `404 Not Found` if auto-indexing is enabled for `/`:

```
location / {
  alias /my/path/;
  index index.html;
}
```

Correct definition:

```
location / {
  root /my/path/;
  index index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just do like what is did:

**CentOS / Fedora**

```
sudo usermod -a -G your_user_name nginx

chmod 710 /home/your_user_name
```

**Ubuntu / Debian**

```
sudo usermod -a -G your_user_name www-data

sudo chown -R :www-data /path/to/your/static_folder
```

And in your nginx file that serve your site make sure that your location for `static` is like this:

```
location /static/ {
        root /path/to/your/static_folder;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To those that **got locked out of ssh** by following @sandes 's answer for Ubuntu. You need to somehow regain access as user with permissions and run this command

```
sudo gpasswd -d www-data your_user
```

This removes the www-data user from the group and allows you to log back in.

Answer (score 0):

I bang my head on this 403 problem for quite some time.
I'm using CentOS from DigitalOcean.

I thought to fix the problem was just to set SELINUX=disabled in /etc/selinux/config but I was wrong. Somehow, I screwed my droplet.

This works for me!
sudo chown nginx:nginx /var/www/mydir

Answer (score 0):

My nginx is run as nginx user and nginx group, but add nginx group to **public folder** not work for me.

I check the permission as a nginx user.

```
su nginx -s /bin/bash
```

I found the I need to add the group for the full path. My path is start at /root, so I need to do following:

```
chown -R :nginx /root
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option to this is puting your static in `/var/www/static/`

and changing your `/etc/nginx/sites-available/projectname` to

```
 location /static/ {
        root /var/www;
    }
```

or

```
 location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/static;
    }
```