# Nginx - 403 error only on static files

Tags: django, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, gunicorn, nginx-config

The stack is: Ubuntu // Supervisor // Nginx <--> Gunicorn <--> Django 1.11

Static files folder: `/home/sitebiz/sitebiz/static/`

Nginx config: `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site.biz`

```
server {
        listen   80;
        listen   [::]:80;
        access_log off;
        server_name site.biz;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    #listen              80 ssl;
    server_name         site.biz;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.biz/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.biz/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    #listen 80;

    gzip on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx-error.log;


    location /static {
        root  /home/sitebiz/sitebiz;
        internal;
    }

    location /track {
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE $geoip_country_code;
        proxy_set_header GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME $geoip_country_name;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8899;
            break;
        }
    }

    location /income {
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE $geoip_country_code;
        proxy_set_header GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME $geoip_country_name;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8899;
            break;
        }
    }


    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE $geoip_country_code;
        proxy_set_header GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME $geoip_country_name;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change the `/home/sitebiz/sitebiz/static/` directory and all of its content ownership to **sitebiz** user and to **www-data** , but none helped.
Not even Django itself can serve static files and I have no idea why.

From django settings:

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(name)) 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') 
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `root  /sitebiz/sitebiz;` this does not lead to `/home/`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, why it was mangled here. The block is 
        
        **location /static/ {
                root  /home/sitebiz/sitebiz;
                internal;
            }**

Comment: Is there an entry in the `nginx` error log? Also, does the `nginx` worker username have read access to all of the directories above `/home/sitebiz/sitebiz/static/`?

Comment: In the **Project** directory: 

**drwxr-xr-x 18 sitebiz sitebiz   4096 Aug 23 17:32 static**

In the **static** directory 

drwxr-xr-x 16 sitebiz sitebiz 4096 Aug 23 17:57 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 sitebiz sitebiz 4096 Aug 23 17:30 admin
drwxr-xr-x  2 sitebiz sitebiz 4096 Aug 23 17:32 angular
drwxr-xr-x  6 sitebiz sitebiz 4096 Aug 23 17:32 bootstrap
.... 
and so on ........

Comment: location  /static {} remove slash

Comment: @marin , thank you, but unfortunately it did not help

Comment: Did you run `collectstatic`? What does your `STATIC_ROOT` look like in your settings.py in your Django project?

Comment: @ScottSkiles, 

**SITE_ROOT** = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))

**MEDIA_URL** = '/media/'
**MEDIA_ROOT** = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

**STATIC_URL** = '/static/'
**STATIC_ROOT** = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')

Comment: Did `collectstatic` work? 403 error is forbidden. You might need to `chown` the directory you want to collect the static files into, collect them, then `chown` it back. Also, Fabric is helpful for this stuff if this is indeed the issue: http://www.fabfile.org/

Comment: can you show your django settings, and URL-s

Comment: @ScottSkiles, no, unfortunately, does not work. I tried chowning to **www-data** and back to **sitebiz** user.

Comment: @marin, can settings file help if Nginx is the one that serves the files in /static directory?

Comment: @gencurrent can you share URL of static file you are trying to access? And actual path to that file.

Comment: @IvanStarostin, /home/sitebiz/sitebiz/static

Comment: ...is that a file path or a file URL? Or you are trying to view static directory in browser? @gencurrent

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea, why, but the solution from the [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808813/nginx-serve-static-file-and-got-403-forbidden) works fine

Just execute in shell:

```
sudo chmod o+x /root
```

If someone could explain this logic - why root folder must have Execute permission - I would be very thankful (and upvoteful)