# What's wrong with this Nginx configuration that can't locate media directory?

Tags: python, django, nginx, redis, gunicorn

I am working with a demo Django project of video blog that I have hosted on a local Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS with Gunicorn, Nginx, Redis and Postgresql. I have installed this server on Virtualbox and assigned a fixed IP. Static files (html, css, js) are working well but video and a default image file of media folder are not showing. Both static and media folders are in the project root directory. I think have not configured properly the Nginx configuration file. But everything works fine when I check them with development server. I'm very new my dear and have a lack of advance programming knowledge. That's why, I am asking for your help for solving this problem. Please have a look the code bellow if there is any mistake. Thanks in advance!

**Error from browser console**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) /media/videos/2019/10/02/Algebra_Basics-_What_Is_Algebra_-_Math_Antics.mp4:1
```

**Project structure**

[image]

**part of settings.py file**

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'kiji/static')
]    

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# For sending email
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'


# Redis Configuration
REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
REDIS_PORT = 6379
REDIS_DB = 0
```

**Nginx congiration**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.1.44;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/djangoadmin/pyapps/kiji_project/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/djangoadmin/pyapps/kiji_project/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

**Gunicorn's confiration**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=djangoadmin
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/kiji_project
ExecStart=/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          kiji.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**models.py file for videos**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from teacher.models import Teacher
from django.urls import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING, 
                                blank=True, null=True,
                                related_name='blog_teachers')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='blog_posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)    

    clip = models.FileField(upload_to = 'videos/%Y/%m/%d/')

    description = models.TextField(max_length = 2400, blank = True)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', args = [self.id])
```

**models.py file for default image**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)    
    present_address = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    permanent_address = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length = 14, unique = True, null=True)    
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(default = 'default_profile.jpg', upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d/')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.profile_picture.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.profile_picture.path)
```

Comment: You miss a semicolon at line 134

Comment: @Wonka Sorry I can't understand. Could you please make it more detail?

Comment: We can't understand also.

Comment: @Wonka thanks for your time.

Comment: nginx most likely does not have the permission to read the file from that location.

Comment: @ShawnC. Thanks a lot for coming to help me. How to allow nginx to read the data from that location?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx serve static file and got 403 forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808813/nginx-serve-static-file-and-got-403-forbidden)

Comment: @ShawnC. Thanks again for your recommendation. It will take time to understand them. I will let you know the result my dear.