# Nginx user cannot access Ubuntu folder

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I'm running Nginx on a Ubuntu server. Nginx does not have permission to access my project folder as show below.

```
sudo -u www-data stat /home/mainuser/projectname/
stat: cannot statx '/home/mainuser/projectname/': Permission denied
```

I know it's an issue specific to this project folder and user because

```
sudo -u www-data stat /home/mainuser/
```

and

```
sudo -u mainuser stat /home/mainuser/projectname/
```

also runs fine.

I've been trying to follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808813/nginx-serve-static-file-and-got-403-forbidden) and so I've tried the following solutions... I tried setting

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/mainuser/projectname/
```

and

```
sudo chown -R :www-data /home/mainuser/projectname/
```

and when I run `ls -l`

I can see these permissions have been applied to the directory

```
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 7 mainuser www-data 4096 May 28 05:13 projectname
```

But still the Nginx `www-data` user does not have permissions to access the dir. What am I missing, how do I give this user access to this directory?

EDIT:

I made another dir `/test` and even after `sudo chmod 777 test/` I do not have permission to access it as the Nginx user either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upstream directory `mainuser` was missing permissions.

Even though

```
sudo -u www-data stat /home/mainuser/
```

worked, the following gave a permission error which clued me in.

```
sudo -u www-data ls /home/mainuser/
```

After that `sudo chmod :www-data /home/mainuser` fixed it