# django static files are not loading on production server nginx

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx

when I don't specify my port number in my url, static files are not loaded in that case.
It works fine for xyz.com:8000 all the static files are loaded But when i use xyz.com, it doesn't load any static files.
I'm using nginx server.

this is my nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name santhals.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
    root /home/ubuntu/santhals/myapp/;
}


    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

refer this may help?

[Nginx serve static file and got 403 forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808813/nginx-serve-static-file-and-got-403-forbidden)

I peeked into your work (sorry but I couldn't help it) and browser said 403 forbidden.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your `Nginx` configs look fine and if there are no permission and access issues, it should work.

A few things to check:

1. Make sure `django.contrib.staticfiles` is included in the `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py` file.
2. Make sure `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` variables are properly set in your `settings.py` file. Generally, they should be pointing to the `static` directory that is located in the root of your project.
3. Make sure you run `python manage.py collectstatic` before deploying your application