# nginx throwing a 403 on localhost, possibly due to OS X High Sierra?

Tags: macos, nginx, macos-high-sierra

I have nginx running on my Macbook Pro and when I try to view the root directory set in the conf file nginx throws a 403. I get the same error with the latest builds of Chrome and Firefox.

The error log shows `failed (13: Permission denied)`, despite the fact that the directory has been chmod'ed with 777. I have confirmed that the correct root directory is set in the conf file. I have stopped and restarted nginx multiple times, and have also stopped nginx, restarted my machine, and then restarted nginx. Still getting a 403.

I recently updated to OS X High Sierra. In troubleshooting this issue I noticed that a [security feature in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586166/why-does-nginx-return-a-403-even-though-all-permissions-are-set-properly) has caused a similar problem for other uses. Could High Sierra be responsible for this problem? Either way, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by moving the target directory out of `~/Documents/` and into the base directory.

Apparently nginx's inability to access the target directory wasn't due to a permissions issue, but perhaps because Documents is a virtual directory and its "real" path is too long for nginx to parse. No idea whether this is due to a change in High Sierra or not.