# PHP MySQLi permission denied but working from MySQL CLI

Tags: php, mysql, apache, selinux

I'm receiving the error

```
Failed to connect to MySQL: Permission denied
```

When connecting from PHP with MySQL, MySQLi and PDO to a remote MySQL host.

However, if I connect to the same host, with the same credentials through MySQL from the same host on the command line it works perfectly.

So I'm making the assumption its a PHP config problem?

Connecting FROM

```
PHP 5.6.40 (Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev)

MySQL 5.5.59
```

Connecting TO

```
PHP 5.6.23 (Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev)

MySQL 5.5.52
```

Anyone got any ideas why I can connect from the command line to MySQL but not from PHP to the same host with the exact same credentials?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess that you have SELinux enabled on your server.
By default it doesn't allow apache process to initialize outgoing network connections.

Copy of an answer from https://serverfault.com/a/456875/442205

To check SELinux

```
sestatus
```

To see what flags are set on httpd processes

```
getsebool -a | grep httpd
```

To allow Apache to connect to remote database through SELinux

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Use -P option makes the change permanent. Without this option, the boolean would be reset to 0 at reboot.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Comment: You are my savior! Thank you.