# Keep getting Nginx 403 Forbidden error when accessing a react js application

Tags: reactjs, nginx, deployment, centos

please, I have a react js application that I want to deploy on my server (Centos 7), I have already generated the build and I have installed nginx on my server and I have created the folder www under `/var/` where I have put the content of my build following the path : `/var/www/merchant-dashboard/html`.

[image]

and I have already allocated the 777 permissions for the `www` folder and all its subdirectories and files

[image]

I created my configuration file under `/etc/nginx/conf.d` and named it `merchantDashboard.conf` here is its content :

[image].

I have also set the permissions for the nginx user with the command
`sudo chown -R nginx:nginx *`.
(my user is called nginx) but I still get the `403 forbidden` error.
Here is my error logs :

[image]

if someone can help me please

Answer (score 0):

I followed this answer:
[Why does Nginx return a 403 even though all permissions are set properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586166/why-does-nginx-return-a-403-even-though-all-permissions-are-set-properly#answer-26228135)

When I disabled SELinux it worked.

Following command from the above mentioned link solved the problem:
`chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/www`