# RTMP Video on demand (vod) issue with plablack in vlc

Tags: nginx, streaming, vlc, rtmp

I created an Nginx RTMP Vod plackback from a server, the Nginx config file is

```
rtmp { 
server {
            listen 1935;

             allow play all;
        application vod {
                        play /root/play/;
                }
    }
}
```

When i try opening from VLC through Network strem, i am getting this error

*VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtmp://link:1935/vod/lt.mp4'. Check the log for details.*
and when i check the message logs its showing

*avcodec error: Failed to open rtmp://link:1935/vod/lt.mp4: Operation not permitted*

also in server under access log of Nginx, i am getting,

- [05/Oct/2020:13:17:03 +0000] PLAY "vod" "mp4:lt.mp4" "" - 382 430 "" "LNX 9,0,124,2" (1s)*

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: Try to chmod /root and /root/play directories with 755
More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6796648/557432

Comment: Hi @tomomiha , thanks. I got it to work, it was an issue with both permission and the path it's trying to fetch from Nginx.